# Working with custom Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, arrays, exception, try-catch

first post here and a new-ish to programming in Java. For one of my assignments, we were asked to create a program that had objects in an array that are cars with certain fields for the information, and then using this we have to determine through custom exceptions whether or not the car will be displayed. I am not completely finished, but for some reason whenever I run my program, it always throws the exception. Any help of pointers would be appreciated, hope my code isn't too bad!

This is my main:

```
package throwusedcarexceptions;

public class ThrowUsedCarExceptions {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int vNumber, year, miles;
    String make;
    double price;

    try{
        UsedCar[] cars = new UsedCar[2];

        cars[0] = new UsedCar(1234, "Honda", 2001, 78340, 5999.99);
        cars[1] = new UsedCar(1235, "Ford", 2005, 78340, 5999.99);

        for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
            System.out.println(cars[i]);
        }
    }

    catch(UsedCarException error){
        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

Then my class to determine whether or not to throw the exception:

```
package throwusedcarexceptions;


public class UsedCar {

int vNumber, year, miles;
String make;
double price;

public UsedCar(int vNumber, String make, int year, int miles, double price) 
throws UsedCarException{
    setVNumber(vNumber);
    if(vNumber < 1000 || vNumber > 9999)
        throw(new UsedCarException());

    setMake(make);
    if(!"Ford".equals(make) || !"Honda".equals(make) || 
!"Toyota".equals(make) || !"Chrysler".equals(make) || !"Other".equals(make))
        throw(new UsedCarException());

    setYear(year);
    if(year < 1990 || year > 2014)
        throw(new UsedCarException());

    setMiles(miles);
    if(miles < 0)
        throw(new UsedCarException());

    setPrice(price);
    if(price < 0)
        throw(new UsedCarException());
}

public void setVNumber(int vNumber){
    this.vNumber = vNumber;
}

public void setMake(String make){
    this.make = make;
}

public void setYear(int year){
    this.year = year;
}

public void setMiles(int miles){
    this.miles = miles;
}

public void setPrice(double price){
    this.price = price;
}

public int getVNumber(){
    return vNumber;
}

public String getMake(){
    return make;
}

public int getYear(){
    return year;
}

public int getMiles(){
    return miles;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
}
```

And finally my exception class:

```
package throwusedcarexceptions;


public class UsedCarException extends Exception {

public UsedCarException(){
    super("Error: Not a valid input");
}
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: As you are calling the setters from the constructor: why not put the checking and exception raising into the setters? That way you'll have it also when one of the setters is called on the object.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but our assignment said for us to have the exception raising in the constructor for whatever reason, so I just left it there.

Comment: Then consider not adding setters. Bring it up in the discussion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, when you throw an exception, it's a good practice to log it (System.out is sufficient in this case) and print the details about what and where has happened - for instance, the value that caused the exception. So use at least:

```
public UsedCarException(String message) {
    super("Error: Not a valid input " + message);
}
```

---

The problem is in the line which is evaluated as `true` when the `make`is equal to `Honda`:

```
if (!"Ford".equals(make) || !"Honda".equals(make) || !"Toyota".equals(make) || 
    !"Chrysler".equals(make) || !"Other".equals(make)) {throw (new UsedCarException());}
```

Please, use `{}`. Change the lines above it to the following one or feel free to apply De Morgan's laws where `!(A or B)` equals `(!A and !B)`.

```
if (!(
    "Ford".equals(make)   || "Honda".equals(make) || "Toyota".equals(make) || 
    "Chrysler".equals(make) || "Other".equals(make))) 
{
        throw (new UsedCarException());
}
```

Finally, this is still a very ugly condition. Why not check whether the value is included in an array or a List?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Ford", "Honda", "Toyota", "Chrysler", "Other");
if (!list.contains(make)) {
    throw (new UsedCarException());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I really appreciate the advice for logging exceptions, that is definitely a fantastic idea. We just started learning about them this week so it's all still fresh and new to me. Also, the last suggestion is a good idea. Awkwardly enough, this is a level 2 class that I got put into with little learning in the first level so I am not the best at arrays and what not. I will make note of this for the future!

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
if(!"Ford".equals(make) || !"Honda".equals(make) || 
        !"Toyota".equals(make) || !"Chrysler".equals(make) || 
        !"Other".equals(make))
    throw(new UsedCarException());
```

will always throw an exception because `make` will be not equal to all (or all but one) of the makes. You probably want this instead:

```
if(!("Ford".equals(make) || "Honda".equals(make) || 
        "Toyota".equals(make) || "Chrysler".equals(make) || 
        "Other".equals(make)))
    throw(new UsedCarException());
```

or else just change all the `||` to `&&`.

Comment: I will make these adjustments as soon as I am able to, thanks for the suggestion! I thought this was where my issue would be, but I wasn't quite sure. I appreciate the help!